# How To Create Test Facebook Ads || How to Get Android Advertisement ID (AAID) programmatically?

Tags: android-facebook

How to create Test Device to Facebook Ads >> To Create Test Device you need Enter **a device ID (IDFA, AAID):**

sometimes we need to get the android advertisement id AAID for android device, when we place google ads or Facebook ads to our Android app or any other functions we need to place the unique AAID for testing purpose.

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin code

```
Thread{
        AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(activity).id?.let {
            Log.i("myId",it)
        }
    }.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first Step, get [AdvertisingIdClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient?fbclid=IwAR2VN3cx77zLVRl-Qucr5bQOz1GKkdK2tRHVa4TWPBDtGpUV-FLzDPXkjZE)

public class AdvertisingIdClient extends Object
Helper library for retrieval of advertising ID and related information such as the limit ad tracking setting.

It is intended that the advertising ID completely replace existing usage of other identifiers for ads purposes (such as use of ANDROID_ID in Settings.Secure) when Google Play Services is available. Cases, where Google Play Services is unavailable, are indicated by a GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException being thrown by getAdvertisingIdInfo().

Code >>>

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String token = null;
        AdvertisingIdClient.Info adInfo = null;
        try {
            adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext());
        } catch (IOException | GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAv
            // ...
            MessageLog.setLogCat("DEVICE_ID",""+e);
        }
        String android_id = adInfo.getId();
        MessageLog.setLogCat("DEVICE_ID",android_id);
        return android_id;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
        MessageLog.setLogCat("DEVICE_ID","DEVICE_ID Access token retrieved:" + token);
    }
};
task.execute();
```

Open Your Logcate of android studio
you will get Result like it

```
2020-07-23 19:32:37.225 19041-19093/com.packagename.example I/DEVICE_ID :: 1aaf7707-22b5-4627-xxx-xxxxxxxx
2020-07-23 19:32:37.738 19041-19041/com.packagename.example I/DEVICE_ID :: DEVICE_ID Access token retrieved:1aaf7707-22b5-4627-xxx-xxxxxxxx
```

**1aaf7707-22b5-4627-xxx-xxxxxxxx is your device ID**
Second Step: Open your [Facebook Monetization Manager](https://business.facebook.com/)
[image]
write your device id in a device ID (IDFA, AAID): EditText and Write Name Device like the image.

Comment: can you help me out how to get the ad id .

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet might help lot of you in current cases.

Add this method in your code:

```
fun getIdThread() {
    var adInfo: AdvertisingIdClient.Info? = null
    try {
        adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(this)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        // Unrecoverable error connecting to Google Play services (e.g.,
        // the old version of the service doesn't support getting AdvertisingId).
    } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException) {
        // Encountered a recoverable error connecting to Google Play services.
    } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
        // Google Play services is not available entirely.
    }
    val id: String = adInfo?.id.orEmpty()
    val isLAT: Boolean = adInfo?.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled?.orFalse() == true
}
```

And call from separate thread as like below.

```
Thread{
   getIdThread()
}.start()
```

This simple snippet will give you the AD ID. Even if the user resets the advertising ID.

Note: [Don't forget to declare ad ID permission in your manifest]